Making a ggplot2 Sankey plot in R less crowded
If I have a dataframe in R (called connections_df), that shows the connections between the two endpoints (endpoint1 and endpoint2) with the corresponding chromosome (CHR):
   endpoint1         endpoint2           CHR      total_connections
   <chr>             <chr>             <dbl>                 <int>
 1 Acute Ulceration  Body Image            6                   1
 2 Acute Ulceration  Breast Symptoms       6                   1
 3 Acute Ulceration  RILA                 17                   1
 4 Acute Ulceration  Telangiectasia G1     6                   1
 5 Acute desqumation Acute Ulceration      2                   20
 6 Acute desqumation Acute Ulceration      5                   20
 7 Acute desqumation Acute Ulceration      6                   20
 8 Acute desqumation Acute Ulceration      8                   20
 9 Acute desqumation Acute Ulceration      9                   20
10 Acute desqumation Acute Ulceration     10                   20

I plot this data using a sankey diagram using ggplot. The code is below. I notice however my plot looks squished, you cannot see the labels for some of the endpoints. Is there a way to fit everything in the plot so its easier to see because right now the top endpoints Acute desqumation Acute Ulceration  take so much space (because the links represent / are proportional to the total_connectons). Is there a way to scale it so everything fits. I've even tried ggsave and set the width and height and yet still the plot is not scaled properly.
Code:
sankey <- ggplot(data = connections_df,
               aes(axis1 = endpoint1, axis2 = endpoint2, y = total_connections / 10)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = CHR)) +
  geom_stratum() +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Endpoint 1", "Endpoint 2"), expand = c(0.1, 0.1)) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE, name = "Chromosome") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Sankey Plot of Endpoint Connections by Chromosome",
       x = NULL,
       y = "Number of Connections")

Plot picture: you can see the labels for the endpoints at the bottom right is very squished.


You can use ggrepel to space the text a bit with geom_text_repel(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum)), direction="y", min.segment.length = Inf), but then it no longer aligns with  your geom_stratum, The only way I can think of, while maintaining the ratios between total_connections  is to explicitly set the aspect ratio with theme(aspect.ratio = 20) and save a sufficiently large image.  Using a non-linear y-scale would also work, but then you'd sacrifice the  ratios between total_connections.
